# How to calculate the smallest sum of squared differences among 5 variables

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, least-squares

I would like to calculate in *Gnu R* the smallest sum of squared differences between `w`,`x`,`y`,`z` and `a` and choose which of this four variables fits `a` best, but I have no clue about how to do it in the most elegant way.

Consider the following random data:

```
set.seed(5840)
a <- runif(100, -1.5, 1.5)
w <- pnorm(rnorm(100))
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- dnorm(rnorm(100))
```

Does somebody know how to do that?

Comment: Does `lapply(list(w,x,y,z), function(xx) sum((lm(a ~ xx)$fitted.values-a)^2))` produce what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
sapply(data.frame(w, x, y, z), function(v) sum((a - v) ^ 2))
#        w         x         y         z 
# 95.39201 158.81291 186.37518  75.86112
```

The smallest sum of squared differences is obtained for `z`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sven, this is the answer I understand best!

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is answered, but as a new member I'd post a reply, by way of learning the ropes round stackoverflow. 
So here goes. Please bear with me.

Just building on above two answers actually

```
sort(apply(cbind(w, x, y, z), 2,function(v) sum((a - v) ^ 2)))[1]
```

And following nicola's approach,

```
    sort(apply(cbind(w,x,y,z),2, function(xx) sum((lm(a ~ xx)$residuals)^2)))[1]
```

And an edit: 
 We can use names() to get the name of the column obtained above

Comment: Thank you, R.S., for providing another solution on how to deal with the problem!